# delete a line in .txt using python by matching the number in the line

Tags: python

I finally came to my last part.. and I'm stuck..

In my orderlist.txt file I have

```
[99 ,1, "3/03/2011", ["ScrewDriver", "Hammer", "Stone"]]
[2 ,2, "3/03/2011", ["hammer,nails"]]
[31 ,2, "3/03/2011", ["plaster,studd"]]
[100 ,2, "3/03/2011", ["hammer,studd"]]
```

my code:

```
def delorder():
    f=open('orderlist.txt',"r+")
    lines=f.readlines()
    num_del=int(input("what is the ordernumber to be deleted:"))
    new=""

    for line in lines:
        listline=eval(line)
        if not(num_del==list_line[0]):
            new +=(line + "\n")
        return (new)
```

at this part it give me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/cscs 120 testint in lab/assignment 1/Customer assignment 1/Customer assignment 1/testing oder", line 13, in <module>
    print(delorder())
  File "E:/cscs 120 testint in lab/assignment 1/Customer assignment 1/Customer    assignment 1/testing oder", line 8, in delorder
    listline=eval(line)
  File "<string>", line 1
    [99 ,1, "3/03/2011", [“ScrewDriver”, “Hammer”, “Stone”]]
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

My objective of this function is to get an input number example:31 and it will delete-->
[31 ,2, "3/03/2011", ["plaster,studd"]], which at the end in the orderlist.txt it would not appearr this line [31 ,2, "3/03/2011", ["plaster,studd"]] but the left over lines.
plz help

Comment: I beleive it has something to do with the "smart-quotes" in that line.  (They are also known as curved-quotes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you see them, but look closely at those quotation marks:

```
[1,'1','3/03/2011', [“ScrewDriver”, “Hammer”, “Stone”]]
```

There's a difference between this:

```
”
```

and this:

```
"
```

The first one (`”`) is a curly quote, which screws up the interpreter. Use normal quotes (`"`) and post back what your script returns then.

Also, what does this `return` statement do:

```
return (new)
```

If you're in a function, the function will quit upon the first iteration of the list, as it `return`s every single loop, but only the first one is caught and the function dies there.

I'd move the `return` statement down a level so it isn't part of the `for` loop. So change this:

```
for line in lines:
    listline=eval(line)
    if not(num_del==list_line[0]):
        new +=(line + "\n")
    return (new)
```

To this:

```
for line in lines:
    listline=eval(line)
    if not(num_del==list_line[0]):
        new +=(line + "\n")

return (new)
```

---

This is your text file without the curly quotes. Try copy and pasting it:

```
[99 ,1, "3/03/2011", ["ScrewDriver", "Hammer", "Stone"]]
[2 ,2, "3/03/2011", ["hammer,nails"]]
[31 ,2, "3/03/2011", ["plaster,studd"]]
[100 ,2, "3/03/2011", ["hammer,studd"]]
```

Comment: ok sorry i edit my script on the top again.. i made a little bit changes.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:/cscs 120 testint in lab/assignment 1/Customer assignment 1/Customer assignment 1/testing oder", line 13, in <module>
        print(delorder())
      File "E:/cscs 120 testint in lab/assignment 1/Customer assignment 1/Customer assignment 1/testing oder", line 8, in delorder
        listline=eval(line)
      File "<string>", line 1
        [99 ,1, "3/03/2011", [“ScrewDriver”, “Hammer”, “Stone”]]
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: @Yuvin Ng, the curly quotes are still there in the text you pasted. Can't you see them? Look closely.

Comment: @Yuvin Ng: I've replaced them for you, so just copy and paste that text file chunk from my answer and see if it works.

Comment: oh i know why now... the reason is because i copy the list from microsoft word... i thouhgt is the same.. sorry..

Comment: @Yuvin Ng: whatever you do, don't use MS Word for programming. Use Notepad, as it doesn't use curly quotes.

Comment: ok thank you ! i got it done..  im gonna try to f.write() it back to the .txt file and see what happen.. get back to you.